# Problema posicionando elementos en menú responsivo

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy haciendo un menú pero tengo un problema porque lo diseñe algo así como dos filas: una con unos botones y la otra para un botón que vaya debajo y en medio de dos botones de arriba llamados  "mandante" y "autoedificador", pero no sé por qué no logro hacerlo.

También cuando achico la pantalla no es totalmente responsive porque sí me aparece mi botón pero cuando lo pulso los elementos salen uno al lado del otro en vez de uno abajo del otro.

Dejo el codigo de cómo va quedando: (acepto sugerencias de que podría mejorar o cómo podría refinar más el código)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  MENÚ -->
<div class="container-fluid  fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse  container">
    <!-- Boton Home Menu -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right bg-inverse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav d-flex mt-2 ml-auto mr-5" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="bootstrap/img/Home.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block " alt="Logo"></a>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-danger mr-1 menutext menutext">concepto</a>
            <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-danger mr-1 menutext menutext">servicios</a>
            <a href="#" class="col-2 col-md-2 offset-md-3 btn btn-danger mr-1 menutext">mandante</a>
            <a href="#" class="col-2 btn btn-danger menutext">autoedificador</a>
          </div>
          <!-- linea 1-->
          <div class="row justify-content-end mr-5 pr-5">
            <a href="" class="menutext">Regístrate</a>
          </div>
          <!-- linea 2-->
        </div>
        <!-- linea uno del menu -->
      </div>
      <!-- navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- boton -->
  </nav>
  <!-- Barra de Menu -->
</div>
<!-- Contenedor de la barra de menu -->
```

Comment: He puesto el código como ejecutable (con Bootstrap) para que se pueda ver el código en funcionamiento, pero no termina de quedar claro lo que quieres. Deberías agregar una imagen con cómo quieres que se vea y cómo se ve ahora.

Comment: asi se ve amigo:

Comment: asi se ve amigo en pantallas grandes:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ejshvr6t3xnmbd/asiseve.png?dl=0

y asi se ve en pantallas chicas
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia923n5iallngad/pantallachica.png?dl=0

Y asi se uiere en pantalla grandes:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5stl2c5mt5jfdv/asisequiere.png?dl=0

y asi en pantallas chicas
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3irzcbitqaf5awp/asisequierepantallachica.png?dl=0

Se que quizas sea una tema de flex box creo pero lo de centrar el registrate en medio de los dos botones ahi si no tengo mucha experiencia, de hecho este es mi primer proyecto web

Comment: Saludos, ¿y cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener? porque por lo que veo yo, en vez de `<div>` puedes usar los `<li>`, también sería bueno que probaras alguna herramienta online de creación de menus como Bootstrap Menu Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me parece que es mas de organización de código recuerda que bootstrap maneja por lo general 12 columnas y me parece que estas mal con los col-2 es col-md-2, te pongo un ejemplo haber si eso te ayuda a guiarte. No está de más leerte las guías de bootstrap sobre maquetado.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--  MENÚ -->
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">>>LOGO<<</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">CONCEPTO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">SERVICIOS</a></li>            
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">MANDANTE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">AUTOEDIFICADOR</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center"><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></div>
        </div>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
```